# How to prevent hide debug tool bar based on IP in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony2 production environment , I want to show the debug toolbar from my development IP. It should be invisible when accessed from any other ip . How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

A better idea would be to add your IP to the `app_dev.php` file:

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    'YOUR.IP.RIGHT.HERE',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Then you can access the development environment with `/app_dev.php`.

Comment: its not about accessing dev environment . Please read the question

Comment: @halfer Please do as long as you find this question irrelevant

Comment: Using the `dev` environment in this case is the most natural solution. Activating the toolbar in the `prod` mode will require you to mess with the `config(_dev).yml` files.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get debug toolbar in production mode. One way would be to change `.htaccess` file in `web` directory so that front controller can be changed between `app.php` or `app_dev.php` based on ip address. It is not a good idea though. Because every time you will be re-generating cache. Can be a problem during peak load time.